# How to scrape images from DuckDuckGo's image search results in Python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, duckduckgo

I'm creating an application with python that's going to show images scraped from DuckDuckGo's image search results. So I need to get a list of links to the images based on the search. The problem is that the HTML that constitutes DuckDuckGo's image search results does not contain any image tags but instead, the images seem to be stored in division tags. How can I with the help of python scrape those damn links to the images and store them in a variable on my program?

What I want my variable to look like:

```
image_links = ["https://duckduckgo.com/?q=duckduckgo&atb=v166-4_p&iax=images&ia=images&iai=https%3A%2F%2Fupload.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fen%2Fthumb%2F8%2F88%2FDuckDuckGo_logo.svg%2F1200px-DuckDuckGo_logo.svg.png","https://duckduckgo.com/?q=duckduckgo&atb=v166-4_p&iax=images&ia=images&iai=https%3A%2F%2Fupload.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fen%2Fthumb%2F8%2F88%2FDuckDuckGo_logo.svg%2F1200px-DuckDuckGo_logo.svg.png"]
```

[A visualization of DuckDuckGo's HTML structure in its image search results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnbQA.jpg)

**Edit:**

When I scrape the HTML from the URL by doing this:

```
source = urllib.request.urlopen("https://duckduckgo.com/?q=duckduckgo&atb=v166-4_p&iax=images&ia=images").read()
```

it doesn't return any image tags at all.

I am checking that by doing this:

```
source_tree = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')

links = [img.get('src') for img in source_tree.find_all('img', _class='tile--img__img')]

print(f"links: {links}")
print(f"img in source_tree: {'img' in str(source_tree)}")
print(f"source_tree: {source_tree}")
```

Output:

```
links: []
img in source_tree: False
source_tree: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js has-zcm" lang="en_US"><head><meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type"/><title>duckduckgo at DuckDuckGo</title><link href="/s1775.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/><link href="/r1775.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/><meta content="noindex,nofollow" name="robots"/><meta content="origin" name="referrer"/><meta content="duckduckgo" name="apple-mobile-web-app-title"/><link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" sizes="16x16 24x24 32x32 64x64" type="image/x-icon"><link href="/assets/icons/meta/DDG-iOS-icon_60x60.png?v=2" id="icon60" rel="apple-touch-icon"><link href="/assets/icons/meta/DDG-iOS-icon_76x76.png?v=2" id="icon76" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76"/><link href="/assets/icons/meta/DDG-iOS-icon_120x120.png?v=2" id="icon120" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120"/><link href="/assets/icons/meta/DDG-iOS-icon_152x152.png?v=2" id="icon152" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152"/><link href="/assets/icons/meta/DDG-icon_256x256.png" rel="image_src"/><script type="text/javascript">var ct,fd,fq,it,iqa,iqm,iqs,iqp,iqq,qw,dl,ra,rv,rad,r1hc,r1c,r2c,r3c,rfq,rq,rds,rs,rt,rl,y,y1,ti,tig,iqd,locale,settings_js_version='s2472.js',is_twitter='',rpl=0;fq=0;fd=1;it=0;iqa=0;iqbi=0;iqm=0;iqs=0;iqp=0;iqq=0;qw=1;dl='';ct='DK';iqd=0;r1hc=0;r1c=0;r3c=0;rq='duckduckgo';rqd="duckduckgo";rfq=0;rt='A';ra='';rv='';rad='';rds=30;rs=0;spice_version='1396';spice_paths='{}';locale='en_US';settings_url_params={};rl='wt-wt';rlo=0;df='';ds='';sfq='';iar='';vqd='3-146459744347044482638673072010848595657-89706121844226791728716680155105882500';safe_ddg=0;;</script><meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"><meta content="true" name="HandheldFriendly"><meta content="no" name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable"/></meta></meta></link></link></head><body class="body--serp"><input id="state_hidden" name="state_hidden" size="1" type="text"/><span class="hide">Ignore this box please.</span><div id="spacing_hidden_wrapper"><div id="spacing_hidden"></div></div><script src="/lib/l113.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="/locale/en_US/duckduckgo10.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="/util/u345.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="/d2615.js" type="text/javascript"></script><div class="site-wrapper js-site-wrapper"><div class="header-wrap js-header-wrap" id="header_wrapper"><div class="welcome-wrap js-welcome-wrap"></div><div class="header cw" id="header"><div class="header__search-wrap"><a class="header__logo-wrap js-header-logo" href="/" tabindex="-1"><span class="header__logo js-logo-ddg">DuckDuckGo</span></a><div class="header__content header__search"><form action="/" class="search--adv search--header js-search-form" id="search_form" name="x"><input autocomplete="off" class="search__input search__input--adv js-search-input" id="search_form_input" name="q" tabindex="1" type="text" value="duckduckgo"/><input class="search__clear js-search-clear" id="search_form_input_clear" tabindex="3" type="button" value="X"><input class="search__button js-search-button" id="search_button" tabindex="2" type="submit" value="S"><a class="search__dropdown" href="javascript:;" id="search_dropdown" tabindex="4"></a><div class="search__hidden js-search-hidden" id="search_elements_hidden"></div></input></input></form></div></div><div class="zcm-wrap zcm-wrap--header is-noscript-hidden" id="duckbar"></div></div><div class="header--aside js-header-aside"></div></div><div class="zci-wrap" id="zero_click_wrapper"></div><div class="verticals" id="vertical_wrapper"></div><div class="content-wrap" id="web_content_wrapper"><div class="serp__top-right js-serp-top-right"></div><div class="serp__bottom-right js-serp-bottom-right"><div class="js-feedback-btn-wrap"></div></div><div class="cw"><div class="serp__results js-serp-results" id="links_wrapper"><div class="results--main"><div class="search-filters-wrap"><div class="js-search-filters search-filters"></div></div><noscript><meta content="0;URL=/html?q=duckduckgo" http-equiv="refresh"/><link href="/css/noscript.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/><div class="msg msg--noscript"><p class="msg-title--noscript">You are being redirected to the non-JavaScript site.</p>Click <a href="/html/?q=duckduckgo">here</a> if it doesn't happen automatically.</div></noscript><div class="results--message" id="message"></div><div class="ia-modules js-ia-modules"></div><div class="results--ads results--ads--main is-hidden js-results-ads" id="ads"></div><div class="results is-hidden js-results" id="links"></div></div><div class="results--sidebar js-results-sidebar"><div class="sidebar-modules js-sidebar-modules"></div><div class="is-hidden js-sidebar-ads"></div></div></div></div></div><div id="bottom_spacing2"> </div></div><script type="text/javascript"></script><script type="text/JavaScript">function nrji() {nrj('/t.js?q=duckduckgo&t=A&l=wt-wt&s=0&ct=DK&ss_mkt=us&p_ent=website&ex=-1');nrj('/d.js?q=duckduckgo&t=A&l=wt-wt&s=0&ct=DK&ss_mkt=us&vqd=3-146459744347044482638673072010848595657-89706121844226791728716680155105882500&atb=v166-4_p&p_ent=website&ex=-1&sp=0');DDH.wikipedia_fathead=DDH.wikipedia_fathead||{};DDH.wikipedia_fathead.meta={"name":"Wikipedia","src_name":"Wikipedia","is_stackexchange":null,"perl_module":"DDG::Fathead::Wikipedia","unsafe":0,"live_date":null,"src_options":{"language":"en","min_abstract_length":"20","source_skip":"","skip_image_name":0,"is_wikipedia":1,"skip_abstract_paren":0,"skip_abstract":0,"skip_qr":"","is_mediawiki":1,"skip_icon":0,"is_fanon":0,"skip_end":"0","directory":"","src_info":""},"blockgroup":null,"description":"Wikipedia","signal_from":"wikipedia_fathead","tab":"About","producer":null,"production_state":"online","maintainer":{"github":"duckduckgo"},"src_id":1,"dev_milestone":"live","src_url":null,"attribution":null,"dev_date":null,"topic":["productivity"],"status":"live","id":"wikipedia_fathead","example_query":"nikola tesla","created_date":null,"src_domain":"en.wikipedia.org","repo":"fathead","js_callback_name":"wikipedia","designer":null,"developer":[{"name":"DDG Team","url":"http://www.duckduckhack.com","type":"ddg"}]};;};DDG.ready(nrji, 1);</script><script src="/g2124.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">DDG.ready(function () {DDG.duckbar.add({"meta":{"name":"Wikipedia","src_name":"Wikipedia","is_stackexchange":null,"perl_module":"DDG::Fathead::Wikipedia","unsafe":0,"live_date":null,"src_options":{"language":"en","min_abstract_length":"20","source_skip":"","skip_image_name":0,"is_wikipedia":1,"skip_abstract_paren":0,"skip_abstract":0,"skip_qr":"","is_mediawiki":1,"skip_icon":0,"is_fanon":0,"skip_end":"0","directory":"","src_info":""},"blockgroup":null,"description":"Wikipedia","signal_from":"wikipedia_fathead","tab":"About","producer":null,"production_state":"online","maintainer":{"github":"duckduckgo"},"src_id":1,"dev_milestone":"live","src_url":null,"attribution":null,"dev_date":null,"topic":["productivity"],"status":"live","id":"wikipedia_fathead","example_query":"nikola tesla","created_date":null,"src_domain":"en.wikipedia.org","repo":"fathead","js_callback_name":"wikipedia","designer":null,"developer":[{"name":"DDG Team","url":"http://www.duckduckhack.com","type":"ddg"}]},"signal":"medium","data":{"Results":[{"FirstURL":"https://duckduckgo.com","Text":"Official site - DuckDuckGo","Result":"<a href=\"https://duckduckgo.com\"><b>Official site</b></a><a href=\"https://duckduckgo.com\"> - DuckDuckGo</a>","Icon":{"URL":"https://duckduckgo.com/i/duckduckgo.com.ico","Width":16,"Height":16}}],"AbstractSource":"Wikipedia","Abstract":"DuckDuckGo is an Internet search engine that emphasizes protecting searchers' privacy and avoiding the filter bubble of personalized search results. DuckDuckGo distinguishes itself from other search engines by not profiling its users and by deliberately showing all users the same search results for a given search term, and emphasizes returning the best results, rather than the most results, generating those results from over 400 individual sources, including crowdsourced sites such as Wikipedia, and other search engines like Bing, Yahoo!, and Yandex.","Answer":"","Redirect":"","Heading":"DuckDuckGo","ImageWidth":340,"Definition":"","Entity":"website","meta":{"name":"Wikipedia","src_name":"Wikipedia","is_stackexchange":null,"perl_module":"DDG::Fathead::Wikipedia","unsafe":0,"live_date":null,"src_options":{"language":"en","min_abstract_length":"20","source_skip":"","skip_image_name":0,"is_wikipedia":1,"skip_abstract_paren":0,"skip_abstract":0,"skip_qr":"","is_mediawiki":1,"skip_icon":0,"is_fanon":0,"skip_end":"0","directory":"","src_info":""},"blockgroup":null,"description":"Wikipedia","signal_from":"wikipedia_fathead","tab":"About","producer":null,"production_state":"online","maintainer":{"github":"duckduckgo"},"src_id":1,"dev_milestone":"live","src_url":null,"attribution":null,"dev_date":null,"topic":["productivity"],"status":"live","id":"wikipedia_fathead","example_query":"nikola tesla","created_date":null,"src_domain":"en.wikipedia.org","repo":"fathead","js_callback_name":"wikipedia","designer":null,"developer":[{"name":"DDG Team","url":"http://www.duckduckhack.com","type":"ddg"}]},"AnswerType":"","Image":"https://duckduckgo.com/i/adad4e5c.png","RelatedTopics":[{"Result":"<a href=\"/Names_Database\">Names Database</a> - The Names Database is a defunct social network, owned and operated by Classmates.com, a wholly owned subsidiary of United Online. The site does not appear to be significantly updated since 2008, and has many broken links and display issues.","Text":"Names Database - The Names Database is a defunct social network, owned and operated by Classmates.com, a wholly owned subsidiary of United Online. The site does not appear to be significantly updated since 2008, and has many broken links and display issues.","FirstURL":"/Names_Database","Icon":{"URL":"","Height":"","Width":""}},{"Text":"Companies based in Chester County, Pennsylvania","FirstURL":"/c/Companies_based_in_Chester_County%2C_Pennsylvania","Result":"<a href=\"/c/Companies_based_in_Chester_County%2C_Pennsylvania\">Companies based in Chester County, Pennsylvania</a>","Icon":{"URL":"","Width":"","Height":""}},{"Text":"Tor hidden services","FirstURL":"/c/Tor_hidden_services","Result":"<a href=\"/c/Tor_hidden_services\">Tor hidden services</a>","Icon":{"Width":"","Height":"","URL":""}},{"Result":"<a href=\"/c/Perl_software\">Perl software</a>","FirstURL":"/c/Perl_software","Text":"Perl software","Icon":{"Height":"","Width":"","URL":""}},{"Result":"<a href=\"/c/Internet_privacy_software\">Internet privacy software</a>","FirstURL":"/c/Internet_privacy_software","Text":"Internet privacy software","Icon":{"Height":"","Width":"","URL":""}},{"Icon":{"URL":"","Width":"","Height":""},"FirstURL":"/c/Proprietary_cross-platform_software","Text":"Proprietary cross-platform software","Result":"<a href=\"/c/Proprietary_cross-platform_software\">Proprietary cross-platform software</a>"},{"Icon":{"Height":"","Width":"","URL":""},"Text":"Internet search engines","FirstURL":"/c/Internet_search_engines","Result":"<a href=\"/c/Internet_search_engines\">Internet search engines</a>"},{"Text":"Android (operating system) software","FirstURL":"/c/Android_(operating_system)_software","Result":"<a href=\"/c/Android_(operating_system)_software\">Android (operating system) software</a>","Icon":{"Height":"","Width":"","URL":""}}],"AbstractURL":"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DuckDuckGo","AbstractText":"DuckDuckGo is an Internet search engine that emphasizes protecting searchers' privacy and avoiding the filter bubble of personalized search results. DuckDuckGo distinguishes itself from other search engines by not profiling its users and by deliberately showing all users the same search results for a given search term, and emphasizes returning the best results, rather than the most results, generating those results from over 400 individual sources, including crowdsourced sites such as Wikipedia, and other search engines like Bing, Yahoo!, and Yandex.","ImageIsLogo":1,"DefinitionSource":"","DefinitionURL":"","Type":"A","Infobox":{"meta":[{"value":"DuckDuckGo","label":"article_title","data_type":"string"},{"label":"template_name","data_type":"string","value":"infobox website"},{"label":"formatting_rules","data_type":"string","value":"website"}],"content":[{"data_type":"string","wiki_order":0,"label":"Type of site","sort_order":"1","value":"Web search engine"},{"sort_order":"1000","value":"Multilingual","wiki_order":1,"data_type":"string","label":"Available in"},{"sort_order":"1001","value":"Worldwide","wiki_order":2,"data_type":"string","label":"Area served"},{"sort_order":"2","value":"Duck Duck Go, Inc.","wiki_order":3,"data_type":"string","label":"Owner"},{"sort_order":"3","value":"Gabriel Weinberg","data_type":"string","wiki_order":4,"label":"Created by"},{"value":"284 (30, 2018)","sort_order":"4","label":"Alexa rank","wiki_order":5,"data_type":"string"},{"label":"Commercial","wiki_order":6,"data_type":"string","value":"Yes","sort_order":"1002"},{"sort_order":"1003","value":"None","wiki_order":7,"data_type":"string","label":"Registration"},{"value":"Sept 25, 2008","sort_order":"3","label":"Launched","data_type":"string","wiki_order":8},{"value":"Active","sort_order":"1004","label":"Current status","data_type":"string","wiki_order":9},{"wiki_order":10,"data_type":"string","label":"Written in","sort_order":"1005","value":"Perl, JavaScript, Python"},{"data_type":"github_profile","wiki_order":"101","label":"GitHub profile","value":"duckduckgo"},{"value":"duckduckgo","label":"Twitter profile","wiki_order":"102","data_type":"twitter_profile"},{"value":"duckduckgo","data_type":"facebook_profile","wiki_order":"104","label":"Facebook profile"},{"value":{"id":"Q114106","entity-type":"item","numeric-id":114106},"data_type":"instance","wiki_order":"207","label":"Instance of"}]},"ImageHeight":270},"model":"FatheadArticle","duckbar_topic":"About","templates":{"detail":"info_detail"}});});</script><script type="text/javascript">DDG.page = new DDG.Pages.SERP({ showSafeSearch: 0, instantAnswerAds: false });</script><div id="z2"> </div><div id="z"></div></body></html>
[Finished in 0.6s]
```

**What's the reason for this and how can I fix it?**

Comment: Have you solved this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The images are actually stored in `img` tags, they are just nested inside of some `div` elements.

[image: DuckDuckGo Image Search IMG Tags]

You should be able to find all of the images on the page with the CSS selector `img.tile--img__img`.

You could use a library like [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to query for all of those links, like so:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Considering your HTML is in the variable `source`
source_tree = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')

links = [img.get('src') for img in source_tree.find_all('img', class_='tile--img__img')]
```

## Edit

Seems like the issue here is that duckduckgo serves the images page with the use of some JavaScript to display all of the `img` tiles. Since the Python request can only fetch the resources and not execute any JavaScript, then you may need to implement a different solution. See this [other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16159102/4362829) for some options.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have now updated some details in my question that shows the code and what it returns. I am still not able to find any image tags at all from the scraped HTML. Am I using the wrong module?

Answer (score 5):

As duckduckgo doesn't provide any api for image search but it does fetch the image using a request call. 
So I have got this another solution which may work.
Here this solution will only work for a **keyword = book**. Because image search request is using a parameter **vqd** which is dynamic eiter on the basis of searched keyword or the user's machine.

If that can be solved this code will work for any keyword to download any image.

If anyone can decrypt this vqd, just replace :

```
'q': 'book',
```

with

```
'q': keyword,
```

and the rest is fine.

```
from bs4 import *
import requests as rq
import os

# api-endpoint
URL = "https://duckduckgo.com/i.js"
keyword = input('Enter the search keyword : ')

# defining a params dict for the parameters to be sent to the API
PARAMS = {'l': 'us-en',
    'o': 'json',
    'q': 'book',
    'vqd': '3-160127109499719016074744569811997028386-179481262599639828155814625357171050706&f=,,,',
}

# sending get request and saving the response as response object
r = rq.get(url=URL, params=PARAMS)

# extracting data in json format
data = r.json()

img_link = data["results"][0]['image']

img_data = rq.get(img_link).content

# os.mkdir('downloads')
filename = "downloads/" + keyword + ".png"
with open(filename, 'wb+') as f:
    f.write(img_data)

print("File " + keyword + ".png successfully downloaded.")
```

========================= **Updated Answer** =========================

There is a [github package](https://github.com/deepanprabhu/duckduckgo-images-api) available for this also.
The main problem with the above script was the value of that parameter (vqd).
With the help of this package I have created the following script.

```
import requests
import re
import json
import os


def search(keywords):
    url = 'https://duckduckgo.com/'
    params = {
        'q': keywords
    }

    print("Hitting DuckDuckGo for Token")

    #   First make a request to above URL, and parse out the 'vqd'
    #   This is a special token, which should be used in the subsequent request
    res = requests.post(url, data=params)
    searchObj = re.search(r'vqd=([\d-]+)\&', res.text, re.M | re.I)

    if not searchObj:
        print("Token Parsing Failed !")
        return -1

    print("Obtained Token")

    headers = {
        'dnt': '1',
        'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch, br',
        'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,ms;q=0.4',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36',
        'accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
        'referer': 'https://duckduckgo.com/',
        'authority': 'duckduckgo.com',
    }

    params = (
        ('l', 'wt-wt'),
        ('o', 'json'),
        ('q', keywords),
        ('vqd', searchObj.group(1)),
        ('f', ',,,'),
        ('p', '2')
    )

    requestUrl = url + "i.js"

    try:
        res = requests.get(requestUrl, headers=headers, params=params)
        data = json.loads(res.text)
        saveImage(data["results"], keywords)
    except ValueError as e:
        print('Please try later.')

    # logger.debug("Hitting Url Success : %s", requestUrl)


def saveImage(objs, keyword):
    for obj in objs:
        img_link = obj['image']
        img_data = requests.get(img_link).content

        # os.mkdir('downloads')
        filename = "downloads/" + keyword + ".png"
        with open(filename, 'wb+') as f:
            f.write(img_data)

        print("File " + keyword + ".png successfully downloaded.")
        break


while True:
    keyword = input('Enter the search keyword : ')
    # print(keyword)
    search(keyword)
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution was using selenium as proposed in the answer marked as right.

```py
from urllib.parse import unquote 
from selenium import webdriver

def search(query):
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    # For one word queries it will be ok, for complex ones should encode first
    driver.get(f'https://duckduckgo.com/?q={query}&t=h_&iax=images&ia=images') 

    # For now it's working with this class, not sure if it will never change
    img_tags = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('tile--img__img') 

    for tag in img_tags:
        src = tag.get_attribute('data-src')
        src = unquote(src)
        src = src.split('=', maxsplit=1)
        src = src[1]
        yield src

    driver.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from pprint import pprint
    imgs_urls = list(search('sun'))
    pprint(imgs_urls)
```

You'll need selenium python library, that you can install using pip and geckodriver, that may be found in your distribution package manager.

Comment: Thanks it helped me a lot!

Comment: works fine but it needs to be changed  to `img_tags = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'tile--img__img') `to work on newer versions of seletium.

And maybe a `time.sleep` before it to let the page load