# Crawling, can't connect to the site

Tags: python, web-crawler

I have a little issue, because when I want to crawle a site  i get error like: "HTTP Error 404 not found" I tried some ways to fix it, but it didn't work. I can't connect  with the site to get the data.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
import urllib.request

my_url="https://tabletennis.setkacup.com/en/schedule?date=2021-08-29&hall=4&period=1"
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0'
headers={'User-Agent':user_agent,}

request = urllib.request.Request(my_url,None,headers)
uClient = uReq(request)
```

Comment: Interestingly, omitting headers results in a 403 Forbidden error.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like SSL Error if so look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53310545/10515127).

Or you can try `requests` library.

`pip install requests`

```py
import requests

my_url="https://tabletennis.setkacup.com/en/schedule?date=2021-08-29&hall=4&period=1"
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0'
headers={'User-Agent':user_agent,}

response = requests.request(method="GET", url=my_url, headers=headers)
print(response.content)
```

Comment: That definitely works. But the body is just a reference to a javascript file ` <script type="text/javascript" src="/app.ee8b6937d804a7ecda66.js"></script>`
This SO question seems relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16157719/how-to-follow-a-redirect-with-urllib